# MySQL - lock row for reading

Tags: mysql, socket.io, innodb

I am using `socket.io` server and multiple clients are making requests to this server. Server checks a `MySQL` `innoDB` table for data and if there is some data it updates its bit/column in table and send data to requested client.

But the problem is my multiple clients are occasionally getting same data.

Reason I feel is, 2 clients make requests to server exactly same point in time and both get same `MySQL` table row record before it was updated by other client.

Comment: If you use the received data in follow-up select, insert or update then you have to use [FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) within the transaction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locking a row in a MYSQL table during a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149355/locking-a-row-in-a-mysql-table-during-a-transaction)

Comment: [How to properly use transactions and locks to ensure database integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749730/how-to-properly-use-transactions-and-locks-to-ensure-database-integrity)

Comment: @t.niese - the link you shared is something different. Those locking doesn't lock a row for reading. I want to lock read, means the row my one connection is processing should not be read by other connection.

Comment: If you use `FOR UPDATE` then `Other transactions are blocked from updating those rows, from doing SELECT ... FOR SHARE, or from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels.`. So if your isolation level is set up correctly then you can't have two transactions having a `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` on the same row. So either the second transaction fails, or waits until the first `FOR UPDATE` finished.