# How to lock the rows using sequelize on the another transaction

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to manage my database, but many users are using the table concurrently so I should lock the rows which the thread is using. I investigated the docs and find out the lock option, ( lock: true). But is it possible to lock the rows on another transaction? because we are using lambda, so some users are running the function concurrently, I am just wondering if the lock option can lock the rows even on another transaction.

Just let me know if you have any thoughts on this. Thanks

Comment: every transaction  lock its own rows, but all other will notice it and don't overwrite the locked row at the same time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locking a row in a MYSQL table during a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149355/locking-a-row-in-a-mysql-table-during-a-transaction)

Comment: yes. it seems so, but in sequelize, should I use skipLocked: true to skip the locked rows in find query? @nbk

Comment: that you have to test, you use locks so that only one parallel change  happen at the time like semaphoresm so skipping it could cause problems, as i don't know all your ideas , you must test if you don't get into trouble